# Matlab, Compare each column to find same triangle side

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a matrix 3x120000 called model_vertex. It is a point cloud from a stl-file. 3 points specify the vertex of a triangle. All 3 points it starts a new triangle.
I want to find the triangles which have the same triangle side.
That means the triangles should  have 2 identical points.

I hope you can help me. I can solve that problem with 4 for-loops... But the calcuclation time is unbelievably bad.

```
for i=1:length((model_vertex(1,:))/3)%every triangle in model_vertex
  for n=i:length((model_vertex(1,:))/3)%every triangle besides i-triangle
    match=0;
    for j=1:3 %Search all vertex of triangle(i), 
      for k=1:3 %Search all vertex of triangle(n)
        if model_vertex(1,(i-1)*3+j) == model_vertex(1,(n-1)*3+k) &&...
           model_vertex(2,(i-1)*3+j) == model_vertex(2,(n-1)*3+k) &&...
           model_vertex(3,(i-1)*3+j) == model_vertex(3,(n-1)*3+k)
           match=match+1;
          if match == 2
            %triangle neighbour found 
            %save in an array
            break
          endif
        endif
      endfor
      if match ==2
        break
      endif
    endfor
  endfor
endfor
```

Comment: Could you post your current working (but too slow for your needs) code? That will help me and others to answer your question.

Comment: Maybe it is my misunderstanding of the problem, but the coordinates of a vertex is given by a column, and a group of three columns next to each other form a triangle (i.e., a triangle has 3 vertices), the first 3 columns describe the first triangle, columns 4 to 6 the second triangle, etc. How can you have 40000 columns then, it should be a multiple of 3?

Comment: yea your right.  it should mean 40000 triangles. so you have 40000*3 vertex.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using sparse matrix and matrix multiplication.

```
s= sparse(reshape(repmat(1:40000,3,1),[],1),model_vertex(:),1);
out = s * s.';
[x y]=find(out);
```

Or more memory friendly:

```
[x y v]=find(out);
idx = v == 2;
x2 = x(idx);
y2 = y(idx);
```

You can create a `[40000 40000]` sparse matrix represetation of the `[3 40000]` `model_vertex`. Then do matrix multiplication to compute the number of identical points.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but i have a problem with your code.
When i create the sparse matrix s i'm out of the integer area and i get an error

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, leveraging many built-in functions to prevent looping. General idea: describe each triangle as a set of three lines, and then search for other triangles with the exact same lines:

```
% generate dummy data
N = 40000;
model_vertex = randi(25,[3 3*N]);

% give vertices numbers, reduces the problem by a factor 3
[coord_label, ~, coord_id] = unique(model_vertex','rows');
triangle = reshape(coord_id,3,[]); % each column is a triangle, containing the triangle_coords id
triangle = sort(triangle); % this is important, otherwise A -> B vs B -> A is missed

% transform from coordinates to lines. A line is given by two vertices (so
% vertex1 to vertex2, vertex2 to vertex3 and 3 to 1)
[line_label, ~, line_id] = unique(reshape(triangle([1 2 2 3 1 3],:),2,[])','rows'); % a line is given by two vertices

% find matches. Speed up loop by sorting first
[s_line_id,b] = sort(line_id);

% data is sorted. Quick start search by only starting from element for
% which the next element is the same
sel = [s_line_id(1:end-1)==s_line_id(2:end); false];

% no pre-allocation, dont know how many items.
match = [];
for l = find(sel)'
    triangle_id1 = ceil(b(l)/3);

    for k=(l+1):(3*N)
        if s_line_id(l)==s_line_id(k)
            triangle_id2 = ceil(b(k)/3);
            if triangle_id2~=triangle_id1 % check for fake triangle => has same line twice. Shoudld not occur in actual data
                match = [match; [triangle_id1, triangle_id2]];
            end
        else
            continue; % move on to next
        end
    end
end

% verify first solution
model_vertex_r = reshape(model_vertex,3,3,[]);
model_vertex_r(:,:,match(1,:))
```

This runs in under 1 second on my laptop.